# How to get Combox's Edit control handle from subclassed Combox's listbox

Tags: winapi, mfc

I subclassed the combobox's listbox.In the list box's mousehover event , I tried to get the handle of combobox's edit control using below code.

But it returns NULL handle for edit control.

method 1

```
HWND hWndParent = ::GetParent(GetSafeHwnd());
CWnd* pParentWnd = CWnd::FromHandle(hWndParent);
CWnd *pCBEdit = ((CComboBox*)pParentWnd)->GetDlgItem(1001);
```

method 2

```
HWND hWndParent = ::GetParent(GetSafeHwnd());
CWnd* pParentWnd = CWnd::FromHandle(hWndParent);
COMBOBOXINFO cbi = { sizeof(COMBOBOXINFO) };
((CComboBox*)pParentWnd)->GetComboBoxInfo(&cbi);
```

In dialog's onInitDialog() I have the below code.

```
   COMBOBOXINFO cbi = { sizeof(COMBOBOXINFO) };
   m_Combo.GetComboBoxInfo(&cbi);
   m_Lbox.SubclassWindow(cbi.hwndList);
```

The subclass code

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CMyListBox, CListBox)

CMyListBox::CMyListBox(){}

CMyListBox::~CMyListBox(){}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyListBox, CListBox)
    ON_WM_MOUSEHOVER()
    ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()



// CMyListBox message handlers
void CMyListBox::OnMouseHover(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    BOOL bOutside = TRUE;
    CString str;
    HWND hWndParent = ::GetParent(GetSafeHwnd());
    CWnd* pParentWnd = CWnd::FromHandle(hWndParent);
    CWnd *pCBEdit = ((CComboBox*)pParentWnd)->GetDlgItem(1001);

    /*COMBOBOXINFO cbi = { sizeof(COMBOBOXINFO) };
    ((CComboBox*)pParentWnd)->GetComboBoxInfo(&cbi);*/

    VERIFY(m_pwndTarget != NULL);

    UINT ndx = ItemFromPoint(point, bOutside);
    if (!bOutside)
    {
        GetText(ndx, str);      
        pCBEdit->SetWindowText(str);
    }

    CListBox::OnMouseHover(nFlags, point);
}


void CMyListBox::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme = { sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT) };
    tme.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE;
    tme.dwHoverTime = 1;
    tme.hwndTrack = GetSafeHwnd();
    TrackMouseEvent(&tme);

    CListBox::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}
```

Comment: Did you check if `GetParent` is returning the window you expect?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: The drop down list of a combobox has not the combo box as a parent. It is a free popup window and is not visible as a child to the combobox control.

Comment: Yes, GetParent is returning the window which I expect.GetCurSel(), findstring is working fine over that window's handle but GetComboBoxInfo() and GetDlgItem(1001) return's empty handle for edit control. My combox is using dropdown style and not dropdown list.

Comment: Could be a timing issue. Maybe the combobox creates the listbox before the edit control and you immediately subclass the listbox before the edit control exists? Can you show your subclassing code?

Answer (score 2):

There is no relation between the dropdown list box and the combo box control. It is a popup control that doesn't have the combo box control as a parent.

The only way I see would be to enumerate all combo box windows of the process and check if the list box you know belongs to it.

Also there is no edit control if it is a combo box with style `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST`.

Only Combobox controls with `CBS_DROPDOWN` have such an edit control.

Comment: I am using CBS_DROPDOWN style only.In dialog's oninitdialog, I able to get edit control handle  using either GetComboBoxInfo() or GetDlgItem(1001). Whereas from combox's subclassed listbox, using these API's I am unable to get the handle of combobox's edit control.

Comment: Changed my answer.

Comment: I'm fairly certain, that the dropdown list has the combo box as its owner, though. Which `GetParent` (despite its name) would return.

Comment: @IInspectable GetOwner() and GetParent() both are returning same handle only.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to use Spy++ to determine this information anyway. As soon as you interact with Spy++, any potentially opened dropdown lists will close. How did you (try to) determine this information?

Comment: @IInspectable spy++ allows you to search for the ComboLBox style. Also Spy++ shows owner and parent for a window. Before I wrote the answer I checked it out.

Comment: I understand, but once you activate Spy++, any and all dropdown lists collapse. Either you know of a trick I'm unaware of, or you are looking at stale state, that does not represent the actual window hierarchies.

Comment: @IInspectable you are right. It is collapsed. But the list box still exists, it is just invisible. Neither Parent nor Owner ever changes.

Comment: I don't see, how you could possibly conclude that. Spy++ does not monitor window hierarchies in real-time. I guess you'd need some nifty WinDbg scripts to determine, whether or not the parent/owner window changes over time.

Comment: And, does this discussion helps the owner? All you comments just tell me that I am wrong. If the owner of this questions tells us, that GetParent and GetOwner don't return a value in the situation he needs. My attempt to verify the situation was successful.And I gave an answer to this situation,. Even if there are (maybe) rare situations.were we have a GetOwner/GetParent value, it shows that it doesn't help, ow we don't know it... I stop this discussion here.

Comment: Thanks xMRi and IInspectable.Yes, the discussion waas helpful. To reolve my problem, while subclassing listbox  I am assigning combobox's window handle to subclassed listbox member variable m_pParaent. Or else I can use  following code also SetWindowLongPtr(cbi.hwndList, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)CWnd::FromHandle(cbi.hwndCombo));

Answer (score 0):

There is a Microsoft article about how to do that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclass-a-combo-box

Bottom line is that they are using a code snippet like this to obtain the edit control:

```
//  Get the edit window handle to each combo box. 
pt.x = 1; 
pt.y = 1; 
hwndEdit1 = ChildWindowFromPoint(hwndCombo1, pt);
```

When trying, I had to use pt.x= 5 pt.y= 5 but I then get a control of window class "Edit" that receives the keystrokes.